# Best way to Convert pairs of base 10 integers to ascii characters in python

Tags: python, python-2.7, ascii

I am talking to a piece of a test equipment using a serial interface.  The two letter ascii ID of the device is encoded as a base 10 integer in a specific register. Each pair of integers needs to be converted to an ascii character.  My question is what is the best way to do this conversion.  I used the method below but it seems fairly complicated for a such a simple task.

Example

input: `5270`
Desired output: `'4F'` (ascii values of 52 and 70)

```
get the raw register value
>>> result =f4.read_register(0,)
>>> result
5270
convert the integer into a list of chars
>>> chars = [i for i in str(result)]
join the pairs together
>>> pairs = [''.join((chars[x], chars[x+1])) for x in xrange(0,len(chars),2)]
>>> pairs
['52', '70']

>>> pairs = [chr(int(x)) for x in pairs]
>>> pairs
['4', 'F']
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add a bit of maths.

- `/` - Integer division
- `%` - Modulus operator

Code

```
>>> num = 5270
>>> pairs = [chr(num/100),chr(num%100)]
>>> pairs
['4', 'F']
```

And to match desired output

```
>>> ''.join(pairs)
'4F'
```

Comment: I think (even though his problem isn't very clear) that he's actually got a string of one or more 4-char groups like this, not necessarily just a single one. But even so, this answer is trivial to adapt to that case: First break the string into 4-char groups, then do this on each one. Or, alternatively, loop on `%`-ing off 2 digits at a time and `chr`ing them.

Comment: @abarnert Yep. But the OP does mention that the input is `5270`. So I guess he has already refined his input by using some technique.

Comment: In this case the register only contains a single 4 digit integer so the original answer would work.  There are other cases where registers contain larger ascii encoded integers, so abarnert's suggestion would help in that cases.

Comment: @user3067612 Happy to see that it helped you. All the best

Answer (score 4):

In addition to @BhargavRao answer, you can use the [`divmod`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#divmod) builtin:

```
num = 5270
''.join(map(chr, divmod(num, 100)))

# '4F'
```

You can also use string formatting:

```
'{:c}{:c}'.format(*divmod(num, 100))

# '4F'
```

Comment: I was about to hit "Post Your Answer" when this appeared... :)

Comment: I was going to note in my answer that this only works in Python 2, which produces `list`s where Python 3 would produce specialized objects (a `map` object in this case). It has now been noted.

Comment: @TigerhawkT3 The OP is using Py2. However it is necessary to mention that.

Comment: Thanks  @Bhargav Rao, TigerhawkT3 in py3 a map object is created but join does work on map objects.

Comment: @DTing: Yep, [`str.join`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.join) takes any iterable of strings, in both 2.x and 3.x, so you don't have to worry about whether `map` returns a list or a map iterator here (unless you're micro-optimizing your code), so you might as well write the simplest thing that works in both 2.x and 3.x, exactly as you've done.